# Foreign key constraint error when saving data to database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am trying to save data into the `Doctor` table in the database. The table structure is shown below.

The error I get when saving

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
>
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The MERGE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_DoctorClinic_Clinic_DoctorId"

Table structure:

**Doctor**

```
Id 
Name
```

**Clinic**

```
Id 
ClinicName
```

**DoctorClinic**

```
DoctorId 
ClinicId
```

Code:

```
foreach (var clinicId in clinicIds)
{
     DoctorClinic doctorClinic = new DoctorClinic()
     {
           ClinicId = clinicId,
           DoctorId = doctor.Id
     };

     doctorClinicList.Add(doctorClinic);
}

doctor.doctorClinic = doctorClinicList;

var doc = await _docRepo.Create(doctor);
```

**Note**: I think the reason is that `DoctorClinic` requires a `doctorID`, and we don't have the ID as we have not saved it yet.

Comment: rather adding to doctorClinicList.Add  you could try `doctor.doctorClinic.Add(new DoctorClinic {ClinicId = clinicId})` so when you save EF core will automatically updates the newly created doctor id

Comment: `doctor.doctorClinic` is a List, and expects a list.

Comment: don't you see Add if not you need to reference System.Data.Linq, I mean when press "." you should get an Add method which accepts clinic

Comment: @coder_b Sorry. ignore my previous comment. The error I  get is `System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'`

Comment: how do you create doctor object that might help? if it new doctor always you initiate the list doctor.doctorClinic = new List<DoctorClinic>() once you done that you can use add methods. have you got these collections in your dbcontext and virtual?